# Dynamic generation of ViewModel from Model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a model class that contains an array of command operations that can be performed on it. The idea is that the UI for editing that model instance can be dynamically generated at runtime; this I intend to do using dynamic XAML creation. So far, so good.

However the ViewModel is quite another thing. The question is what my dynamic UI elements bind to - they need a property in the ViewModel to bind to, so it would appear that I need to dynamically add properties to the VM instance and suddenly that is looking awfully messy.

Alternatively, if the binding could send an additional parameter that allowed me to bind to a single property that then used that parameter to decide what to do with the value, then that would be a cleaner and simpler solution.

Or: something I don't know or haven't considered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had success with dynamic viewmodel objects using `ICustomTypeProvider` - it allows you to dynamically create binding points which can be built up at runtime.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlight_sdk/archive/2011/04/26/binding-to-dynamic-properties-with-icustomtypeprovider-silverlight-5-beta.aspx

Bear in mind though that if you are planning to do anything more complicated than standard CRUD screens, trying to build up a dynamic MVVM system is non-trivial. You lose out on attached properties, attached behaviours and inserting WPF goodies such as type converters and implicitly-typed ViewModel rendering via DataTemplates becomes problematic.

EDIT: For WPF, you'll probably use the equivalent `ICustomTypeDescriptor`

Answer (score 4):

The easiest option is to use [`ExpandoObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) for your view models (or [`DynamicObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx)-based class, if you want to add any custom behavior):

```
public class MyEditor
{
    public MyEditor()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<ExpandoObject>
        {
            CreateItem(1, "John"),
            CreateItem(2, "Mary"),
            CreateItem(3, "Peter"),
            CreateItem(4, "Sarah")
        };
    }

    private ExpandoObject CreateItem(int id, string name)
    {
        dynamic item = new ExpandoObject();

        item.Id = id;
        item.Name = name;

        return item;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ExpandoObject> Items { get; private set; }
}
```

XAML:

```
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

If the speed is meaningful for you, then your choice is emitting view model types at run-time (see types in [`System.Reflection.Emit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.aspx)).